# add div using appenChild and decrease div using removeChild

Tags: javascript, html, css, fractals

I want to make fractal tree and if i press left click i suppossed to be add new div and if i press right click it supposed to be decrease div, but the left click function didn't work, its supposed to be recursive but it just add one div and if i press left click again nothing happen and the right click also didn't work, all of the div disappear. this is my code

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        div {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #e21d27;
            opacity: 0.8;
            transition: 2s;
        }

        div#start {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;

            transform: translate(300%, 300%);
        }

        div div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        div div:nth-child(1) {
            transform: translate(-42%, -105%) rotate(-37deg) scale(0.8, 0.8);
        }

        div div:nth-child(2) {
            transform: translate(55%, -91%) rotate(53deg) scale(0.6, 0.6) ;
        }

        div:hover {
            transition: 1s;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="start"></div>

    <script>
        var coba =27;
        var leftClick = document.getElementById("start");
        var rightClick = document.getElementById("start");

        leftClick.onclick = function(){
        for ( var i = 0; i< coba; i++ ) {
            var di = document.createElement('div');
            leftClick.appendChild(di);
            }
        }

        rightClick.oncontextmenu = function(){

        for ( var i = 0; i< coba; i++ ) {
            var removedi = document.getElementById("start");;
            removedi.parentNode.removeChild(removedi);  
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Your rightclick function is removing the whole "start" div. `removedi` is set to that div and then you are calling removeChild on its parent, causing it to be removed. That's probably why everything is getting removed when you right click. Instead, you should remove child nodes of the start div.

You probably want something like:

```
var start = document.getElementById('start');
for (var i = 0; i < start.childNodes.length; i++) {
  var child = start.childNodes[i];
  start.removeChild(child);
}
```

I'm not sure why your left-click handler is not doing what you want.

Comment: thank you, it's work! @triangle_man, can you take a look in my left click function it's can not do recurtion